# Is there a better way to view/interact with workitems in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, agile, visio, extreme-programming

I'm in the requirements/design phase of building an application.  We're using VS 2008 and TFS.  I have a bunch of scenarios, and related tasks.  Some of the requirements have changed, and I would like to go through and see which tasks need to be changed/deleted.

It's very difficult to view the overview of the system using any of the existing workitem views - whether it's the grid in VS or viewing them in Excel.

Is there a tool out there that will show me my workitems in a hierarchical view?  Alternatively, I would take something that would export my workitems to Visio so I could interact with them in a virtual "index cards on the whiteboard" way.

Comment: What hierarchy are you referring to? Workitem to related workitem? I don't know of such a tool, and I think you'd have to write one. For ad-hoc use, you may want to use the database directly.

Comment: Yes, related work items.  There's a tool on codeplex called TFS Sticky Buddy which is close, but not quite what i'm looking for.  http://tfsstickybuddy.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchical views of WI within Team Explorer should be fully supported in 2010.

The web access power tool provide heirarchical views to some degree.  You'll need to take a look at whether it will meet your needs.

[Visual Studio Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980951.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend taking a look at a tool called [Eylean board](http://www.eylean.com). It transforms TFS work items into sticky note/whiteboard look a like workspace.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2010 has built-in support for hierarchical work items. While Team Web Access does include a grid-based tree view to visualize work item hierarchy, it is still pretty limited. However, coupled with a tool like [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com), Team Web Access allows users to view work items on a virtual Scrum (wall) board and to manipulate them with drag and drop.